# I make an entension to make a substring in swift like C# style ,but it has memory leaks

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, substring

I had make an entension in String,like the C# style,like this:

```
public extension String{
    func MySubstring(Start:Int,lenth:Int) -> String {
        var start:Index=self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: Start);
        var endIndex:Index=self.index(start, offsetBy: lenth);
        var result:String=self.substring(with: start..<endIndex);
        return result;

    }
}
```

and i detected it seems has memory leak,so I just correct it like this:

```
public extension String{
    func MySubstring(Start:Int,lenth:Int) -> String {

        var result:String={
        [unowned self]
        in
        var start:Index=self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: Start);
        var endIndex:Index=self.index(start, offsetBy: lenth);
        return self.substring(with: start..<endIndex);
    }()

    }
}
```

but it shows that

```
'unowned' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'String'
```

So I want to ask if my code has memory leak,and how can I make a substring entension with the C# style?

Comment: I cannot see a memory leak in your code – what *exactly* makes you think it has? What does Instruments report, or the Xcode Memory Graph debugger?

Comment: it is about leak instrument,it shows the  var result:String=self.substring(with: start..<endIndex); 189bytes